# Calculate $\int \limits _0 ^3 \int \limits _1 ^7 7xy \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \Bbb d y \Bbb d x $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

[Here is the link for my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8HJO.jpg)>Calculate

> $$\int \limits _0 ^3 \int \limits _1 ^7 7xy \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \Bbb d y \Bbb d x .$$

I set $u=x^2, \ v=y^2$ and plugged this into the function, but I still do not get the correct answer. I cannot find where is the error. Can anyone help me with it? Thanks!

Comment: Without seeing your work, we cannot find the error.Your approach is a good one.

Comment: I updated my work. Could you please help me to check it? Thanks!

Comment: No, it is not correct. One correct approach is in my answer. You may also find [the correct result (but without the computation) on Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B7+x+y+Sqrt%5Bx%5E2%2By%5E2%5D,+%7Bx,0,3%7D,+%7By,1,7%7D%5D). One reason why your work is not correct is that you don't correctly change the integration bounds when you change the variables.

Answer (score 0):

No need for changes of variables here. Notice that the derivative of $x^2 + y^2$ with respect to $y$ is $2y$, which means that

$$\int \limits _1 ^7 y \sqrt {x^2 + y^2} \Bbb d y = \frac 1 2 \int \limits _1 ^7 \frac {\partial (x^2 + y^2)} {\partial y} \sqrt {x^2 + y^2} \Bbb d y = \frac 1 2 \frac 2 3 \sqrt {x^2 + y^2} ^3 \Bigg| _1 ^7 = \frac 1 3 (\sqrt {x^2 + 49} ^3 - \sqrt {x^2 + 1} ^3) .$$

Moving to the outer integral and using the same idea, this time for $x$,

$$\int \limits _0 ^3 7x \frac 1 3 (\sqrt {x^2 + 49} ^3 - \sqrt {x^2 + 1} ^3) \Bbb d x = \frac 7 6 \int \limits _0 ^3 (x^2 + 49)' \sqrt {x^2 + 49} ^3 \ \Bbb d x - \frac 7 6 \int \limits _0 ^3 (x^2 + 1)' \sqrt {x^2 + 1} ^3 \ \Bbb d x = \\
\frac 7 6 \frac 2 5 \sqrt {x^2 + 49}^5 \Big| _0 ^3 - \frac 7 6 \frac 2 5 \sqrt {x^2 + 1}^5 \Big| _0 ^3 = \frac 7 {15} (\sqrt {58} ^5 - \sqrt {49} ^5 - \sqrt {10} ^5 + \sqrt 1 ^5) = \\
\frac 7 {15} (3364 \sqrt {58} - 16807 - 100 \sqrt {10} + 1) = \frac {14} {15} (1682 \sqrt {58} - 50 \sqrt {10} - 8403) .$$